# IBM Bluemix registry push authentication error

Tags: ibm-cloud, container-registry

When pushing to the Bluemix registry, I get the following error:

```
47c2386f248c: Waiting 
2be95f0d8a0c: Waiting 
2df9b8def18a: Waiting 
unauthorized: authentication required
```

I've got the `cs` and `cr` plugins both installed, an have verified Bx is being added to more auths file. Have tried both using OSX keychain as credstore and without.

When I pull the IBMLiberty example from the BX registry, or build an image with Liberty as the base, it does pull without issue.

I'm running:

```
docker build . -t registry.ng.bluemix.net/my_space/ibm

docker push registry.ng.bluemix.net/my_space/ibm
```

Have also tried manually exporting `BLUEMIX_TRACE=true` and re-running the login and init commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear if you own the namespace `my_space` can you run `bx cr namespaces` to see what namespaces you can push to? If need be you can add one with `bx cr namespace-add <something unique to you>`.

Comment: That's the one! I assumed namespaces would be the same as the spaces you define in your IBM BX web console (labeled spaces), but it's actually the top-level BX org name by default.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure you have logged into the Bluemix Container repository before doing docker push:

```
$ docker pull registry.ng.bluemix.net/myspace/myimage
Using default tag: latest

Please login prior to pull:
Username (bearer): XXXX
Password:
Error response from daemon: unauthorized: authentication required

$ bx cr login
Logging in to 'registry.ng.bluemix.net'...
Logged in to 'registry.ng.bluemix.net'.

$ docker pull registry.ng.bluemix.net/myspace/myimage:4
4: Pulling from myspace/myimage
7b6bb4652a1b: Downloading [===>                                               ]  5.272MB/70.48MB
```

See:

```
$ bx cr login --help
NAME:
   login - Log the local Docker client in to IBM Bluemix Container Registry.

USAGE:
   bx cr login
```

Comment: Thanks. When I run `bx cr login` I get a response that I have logged in successfully - though, no prompt for user/pass. Maybe inheriting from earlier bx login?

On push, though, it is the same authentication error. On pull, it does prompt but does not accept my credentials -- even immediately after `bx cr login` works.

Comment: Hi Ethan, maybe you will need to raise a Bluemix support ticket.

Comment: I just noticed a few more troubleshooting steps you could try here: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Registry/troubleshoot/ts_index.html#ts_index

Comment: Thanks! Just tried this, quota resolved fine (none used, no auth failure), images resolves fine (empty, but no auth failure), and pulling still works fine with the Liberty image. Both bx login and bx cr login work... only thing not working is the actual push!